# No module named 'client' when running Flask web app with Spotipy

Tags: python, flask, importerror, modulenotfounderror, spotipy

I'm encountering an ImportError when trying to run a Flask web app for a music recommender project. The error message I receive is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/music_recommender/app.py", line 4, in <module>
    app = create_app()
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/music_recommender/app/__init__.py", line 18, in create_app
    from app import routes
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/music_recommender/app/routes.py", line 2, in <module>
    import spotipy
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/music_recommender/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/spotipy/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from client import Spotify, SpotifyException
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'client'
```

I believe the issue is related to the spotipy module and its 'client' submodule. However, I'm unsure why it can't find this submodule.

I have cloned the repository from this GitHub link: [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/NicolasTfile/Music_Recommender).

I have tried to run the Flask web app by executing python app.py in the project's root directory.

Instead of the Flask website running successfully, I encountered the ImportError mentioned above.

I have reviewed the code and made sure that I've installed all the necessary dependencies mentioned in the project's requirements.txt file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've cloned the repository and was able to run the project after executing the following steps:

### Update `spotipy` version

The version of `spotipy` that exists inside the project's `requirements.txt` file is outdated. Updating to its latest version fixes the `ModuleNotFoundError` exception you're experiencing. To update the package, run the following command:

```
$ pip install --upgrade spotipy
```

### Fix `NameError` Exception

Even after fixing problem regarding the `spotipy` version, if you try to execute the command `python app.py`, you'll still receive an `NameError`.
It seems that the module `app/routes.py` is trying to reference the object named `app`, that is created by the function `create_app()` from `app/__init__.py` but is unable to find it. To fix this, you can perform the following modifications on the project modules:

#### `app/__init__.py`

Replace the source code from `app/__init__.py` with:

```py
import os

import spotipy
import spotipy.util as sp_util  # Import Spotify utility functions
from config import Config
from flask import (Flask, redirect, redirect, render_template, render_template, request,
                   request, session, session, url_for, url_for)
from flask_session import Session
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth, SpotifyOAuth


# Initialize and configure Flask-Session
session = Session()


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(Config)

    # Configure Flask-Session
    app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'filesystem'
    app.config['SESSION_PERMANENT'] = False
    session.init_app(app)
    return app


app = create_app()
from app.routes import *
```

#### `app/routes.py`

Add the import `from app import app` to the module `app/routes.py`:

```py
from flask import render_template, redirect, url_for, session, request
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth
import spotipy.util as sp_util  # Import Spotify utility functions
import os

from app import app  # <-- Add this import HERE

# Define Spotify API credentials and settings
client_id = os.environ.get('SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID')
# ...
```

#### `app.py`

Instead of the import `from app import create_app`, replace it with `from app import app`. Here's the `app.py` script, with the modified import statement:

```py
from flask import Flask
from app import app


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

After the previously mentioned modifications, you should be able to run the command `python app.py` and access the web app:

[image]

Comment: It finally worked after going through what you said